# Serilog Timestamp @t is not in UTC time

Tags: c#, timestamp, serilog

I'm coding in C# and I have a log file generated with Serilog, written to a file and formatted in Json with CompactJsonFormatter. 
The problem is that the time is not set to the correct timezone, it is in UTC+0.
Is there a method to set the correct timezone for the timestamp? P.S. TimeWrap is deprecated

Example row generated in the log file:

```
{"@t":"2020-02-19T13:34:55.6398202Z","@mt":"Stringa random {stringToLog}","stringToLog":"this"}
```

This is the method i'm using to generate the log:

[image: screenshot of the source code]

Comment: What are you looking for? Your question is not clear

Comment: Is there a method to set the correct timezone for the timestamp? thisi is what i'm looking for. A method or a parameter to set, something to make the timestamp in the correct UTC time of my zone.

Comment: You could have a try the way I did also replace your time zone as required like `UTC-11`

Comment: Has the problem resolved?

Comment: not yet because it's a timestamp which is put automatically from serilog

Comment: You could extract that value  and set on `FindSystemTimeZoneById` that might work

Comment: but i don't know how to extract it because it's put automatically and i don't find any serilog method to do it

Comment: You have to `deserialize` your json and then have to extract that value and finnally need to pass there.

Comment: Please [do not upload images of code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment it is not possible to change how the timestamp is converted to string using the existing `CompactJsonFormatter`... It's [hard-coded](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Formatting.Compact/Formatting/Compact/CompactJsonFormatter.cs#L65) to always get the `UtcDateTime` and then convert it to string.

If you want to change this, you'll have to implement your own version of the `CompactJsonFormatter` by creating your own class that implements `ITextFormatter` and tell Serilog to use that instead.

You can copy the code of the [`CompactJsonFormatter`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Formatting.Compact/Formatting/Compact/CompactJsonFormatter.cs) to your codebase and modify it to suit your needs.

Then you just switch to your custom formatter instead of using the default one:

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(new YourCompactJsonFormatter(), "App.log")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 1):

Serilog.Formatting.Compact project is very "opinionated" and not really configurable.

> https://github.com/serilog/serilog-formatting-compact/blob/dev/src/Serilog.Formatting.Compact/Formatting/Compact/CompactJsonFormatter.cs

If you want to modify the way the formatter works, just copy this file into your project and modify as required.

For UTC, you can modify the below line in this file

```
output.Write(logEvent.Timestamp.LocalDateTime.ToString("O"));
```

to

```
output.Write(logEvent.Timestamp.UtcDateTime.ToString("O"));
```

Then you just switch to your custom formatter instead of using the default one

```
var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.File(new YourCompactJsonFormatter(), "App.log")
    .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure from the context but if you're using appsettings to build your startup  configuration update the "WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE": "Central Standard Time" (or whatever time zone) in your appsettings.json. This will force Serilog to writeTo in that timezone.